# Get all key and values from all redis databases?

Tags: c#, caching, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm using StackExchange.Redis to store and retrieve items in redis cache using multiple databases.

However, I cannot figure out how to retrieve key/values across ALL databases.
The following code retrieves keys from the default database 0, and I cannot find how to change it to retrieve keys from each database

```
    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> GetAll()
    {
        var result = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
        var endpoints = _dataCache.Multiplexer.GetEndPoints();
        var server = _dataCache.Multiplexer.GetServer(endpoints.First());

        var keys = server.Keys();
        foreach (var key in keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(key.ToString());
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

it seems I found the answers - need to pass the database name to the actual .Keys, as below

```
var keys = server.Keys(_dataCache.Database);
```

Comment: Probably not a good idea in production, check out the SCAN command instead.

Comment: which command to be used (KEYS or SCAN) will be decided by server based on server capabilities.

Comment: And how do I get values from keys variable ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write:  var keys = server.Keys(**int dbName**);
I added in the example how to get the values by key

```
public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection
{
   get
   {
      return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("serverName: port");
   }
}

        public Dictionary<string, string> GetDataFromDataBase(srting sPattern = "*")
        {
         int dbName = 2; //or 0, 1, 2
         Dictionary<string, string> dicKeyValue = new Dictionary<string, string>();
         var keys = Connection.GetServer("serverName: port").Keys(dbName, pattern: sPattern);
         string[] keysArr = keys.Select(key =>(string)key).ToArray();

         foreach(var key in keysArr)
         {
           dicKeyValue.Add(key, GetFromDB(dbName , key));
         }

         return dicKeyValue;
        }

    public string GetFromDB(int dbName, string key)
    {
      var db = Connection.GetDatabase(dbName);
      return db.StringGet(key);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using StackExchange.Redis;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string folderPath = @"C:\RedisCache\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + @"\";
                Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
                IDictionary<string, string> dicts = GetDataFromDataBase();

            using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(folderPath + "BatchFile.bat"))
            {
                foreach (var dic in dicts)
                {
                    tw.WriteLine("REDIS COMMAND");
                }
            }

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection
        {
            get
            {
                return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("serverName: port");
            }
        }

        public static Dictionary<string, string> GetDataFromDataBase(string sPattern = "*")
        {
            int dbName = 2; //or 0, 1, 2
            Dictionary<string, string> dicKeyValue = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            var keys = Connection.GetServer("serverName: port").Keys(dbName, pattern: sPattern);
            string[] keysArr = keys.Select(key => (string)key).ToArray();

            foreach (var key in keysArr)
            {
                dicKeyValue.Add(key, GetFromDB(dbName, key));
            }

            return dicKeyValue;
        }

        public static string GetFromDB(int dbName, string key)
        {
            var db = Connection.GetDatabase(dbName);
            return db.StringGet(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add content to this answer

Comment: Please explain how your code fixes the issues presented by the question.